# Service Account fails to list buckets with `403` - `does not have storage.buckets.list access`

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have two different service accounts.

They have the same roles:

```
my-user@my-computer:~$ service_account_basename=working-account
my-user@my-computer:~$ service_account="$service_account_basename@$project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
my-user@my-computer:~$ gcloud projects get-iam-policy "$(gcloud config get-value project)" \
>   --flatten="bindings[].members" \
>   --format='table(bindings.role)' \
>   --filter="bindings.members:$service_account"
ROLE
roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1
roles/compute.securityAdmin
roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
roles/storage.admin
roles/storage.objectViewer
```

---

```
my-user@my-computer:~$ service_account_basename=broken-account
my-user@my-computer:~$ service_account="$service_account_basename@$project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
my-user@my-computer:~$ gcloud projects get-iam-policy "$(gcloud config get-value project)" \
>   --flatten="bindings[].members" \
>   --format='table(bindings.role)' \
>   --filter="bindings.members:$service_account"
ROLE
roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1
roles/compute.securityAdmin
roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
roles/storage.admin
roles/storage.objectViewer
```

One account can list buckets fine:

```
my-user@my-computer:~$ service_account_basename=working-account
my-user@my-computer:~$ service_account="$service_account_basename@$project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
my-user@my-computer:~$ key_file="$service_account_basename.json"
my-user@my-computer:~$ gcloud iam service-accounts keys create "$key_file"  --iam-account "$service_account"
created key [8ead916d3d004522aa6e51608d42e85e] of type [json] as [working-account.json] for [working-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
my-user@my-computer:~$ gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file "$key_file"
Activated service account credentials for: [working-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com]

my-user@my-computer:~$ gsutil ls
gs://bucket-1
gs://bucket-2
gs://bucket-3
gs://bucket-4
gs://bucket-5
```

... where the other fails:

```
my-user@my-computer:~$ service_account_basename=broken-account
my-user@my-computer:~$ service_account="$service_account_basename@$project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
my-user@my-computer:~$ key_file="$service_account_basename.json"
my-user@my-computer:~$ gcloud iam service-accounts keys create "$key_file"  --iam-account "$service_account"
created key [9930c9c6ded24e87a44633aaf35f5ae5] of type [json] as [broken-account.json] for [broken-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
my-user@my-computer:~$ gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file "$key_file"
Activated service account credentials for: [broken-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com]

my-user@my-computer:~$ gsutil ls
AccessDeniedException: 403 broken-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.list access to project 533113984589.
```

The project referenced by the error message is my project, because the number printed out (`533113984589`) is my project's number:

```
my-user@my-computer:~$ gcloud projects describe my-project --format="get(projectNumber)"
533113984589
```

Does someone understand what goes wrong?

Comment: You are trying to manage credentials for gsutil using gcloud. gsutil manages its own credentials. Use gsutil to setup credentials for gsutil.

Comment: Switching `gcloud` account impacts `gsutil`, so I think `gcloud` works fine for managing `gsutil` credentials

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this behavior is related with recreating service account previously deleted and using the same name.

To discard that this is the case, please take a look into the Stackdriver logging by [querying the logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-filters#getting_started_with_advanced_filters) with the following parameters:

```
    resource.type="service_account"
    protoPayload.methodName="google.iam.admin.v1.DeleteServiceAccount"
    resource.labels.email_id="BROKEN_SA@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
```

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#deleting_and_recreating_service_accounts) is explained what I am telling you about creating a new service account with the same name.

Also, you can try by creating a totally new service account, granting the same roles and see how it behaves.